# How to theme help text of field groups in node form

Tags: nodes, entities, 6

I put some HTML tags in the help text of field groups in node form but HTML tags are automatically removed after saved the change. It seems that also there is no selection list of input format for help text. Is there any way to theme it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Help text is run through content_filter_xss():

```
/**
 * Like filter_xss_admin(), but with a shorter list of allowed tags.
 *
 * Used for items entered by administrators, like field descriptions,
 * allowed values, where some (mainly inline) mark-up may be desired
 * (so check_plain() is not acceptable).
 */
function content_filter_xss($string) {
  return filter_xss($string, _content_filter_xss_allowed_tags());
}

/**
 * List of tags allowed by content_filter_xss().
 */
function _content_filter_xss_allowed_tags() {
  return array('a', 'b', 'big',  'code', 'del', 'em', 'i', 'ins',  'pre', 'q', 'small', 'span', 'strong', 'sub', 'sup', 'tt', 'ol', 'ul', 'li', 'p', 'br', 'img');
}
```

Comment: thanks, How can I use the code? Do I need to make a module named "content_filter_xss" with the code?

Comment: no, that is what the cck module uses to "sanitize" those fields.  it is within content.module, so, if you want to change it, you have to modify that module.  it is in cck/content.module wherever modules are stored on your machine.